# Decompose a network into components with equal number of vertices

Tags: r, algorithm, graph, network-programming, graph-algorithm

I need to decompose a simple graph into components with equal fixed number of vertices.
For each component, all the vertices should be connected.

[image: An example of n=3]

For example, for the network above, if we decompose this network into components with n=3 (number of vertices in each component), then the result should be 125;123;124;234. If we decompose this network into components with n=4, then the result should be 1253;1254;1234,5234.

The simplest solution is to list all the possible combinations (C(n,m), m is the number of vertices in the network, n is the number of vertices in each component), then test each combination's connectivity. However, it's not efficient when the network is sparse.

So, any idea? My primary language is R but other languages are fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the set `Sn` of all n-tuples of connected node subsets, construct the set of all n+1-tuples of connected node subsets by iterating over all s={a1,a2,...an} and there iterating over all ai to find a connected node ax which isn't in s. Build s'={a1,a2,...an,ax} and add to `Sn+1` (which, as a set operation eliminate a douplicate).

Taking 125;123;124;234;235, we'd obtain

from 125: 1235;1245

from 123: 1234, (1235)

from 124: (1234), (1245)

from 234: (1234), 2345

from 235: (1235), (2345)

I don't know R, but Java's set operations (given a reasonable set of elements) would be good enough to make this algorithm competitive in a sparse matrix.

Almost forgot: S1 is trivial ;-)

Comment: I have tried BFS. Your algorithm is definitely more efficient.